# RegEx, preg_match_all and filter domains

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

For several hours I'm trying to ride my fair one script and end up almost ready, but it gets weird problem.

Attach a piece of code to get an idea what I mean.

```
$sep = '\.com|\.tv';
$string = 'sub.sub2.sub3.tv-bole-el.com';
$pat = '~[-[:alnum:]]{2,}\b('.$sep.')\b~i';

preg_match_all($pat, $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

In this case in array $matches, it would be correct if you spend tv-bole-el.com

Instead, I earned 2 domains:

- sub3.tv
- -bole-el.com

Anybody have an idea where is wrong?

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Expected output: tv-bole-el.com

Comment: So why does your `$sep` include `.tv` as a valid ending?

Comment: What if you add the `$` anchor to the end of your regex ?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, coz i need it if i want to catch .tv domains from big list.

Comment: @Enissay try but don`t work ;(

Comment: Provide us with a set of inputs and the expected output so we can understand better...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need but this worked for me:

```
$sep = '\.com|\.tv';
$string = 'sub.sub2.sub3.tv-bole-el.com';
$pat = '~[-[:alnum:]]{2,}\b('.$sep.')$~i';
preg_match_all($pat, $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

var_dump($matches[0]);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "tv-bole-el.com"
}
```

Comment: I try it, but after put:

    $string='subdomain1.subdomain2.subdomain3.tv-a-borla.com 7days.com';

Output its:


    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7days.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => .com
        )